# Why can't I pass a function that returns a string, as a parameter of a function, where the parameter is of type string?

Tags: php, method-parameters

Why can't I pass a function that returns a string, as a parameter of a function, where the parameter is of type string?

For example:

```
function testFunction(string $strInput) {
    // Other code here...
    return $strInput;
}

$url1 = 'http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3?key=value';
testFunction(parse_url($url1, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

The above code returns an error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to testFunction() must be an instance of string...

How can I do this?

Comment: PHP is a loosely typed language that does not require you to declare a variable type when declaring a variable.

Comment: Other than the problem with your type hinting you should note that parse_url returns an array, and you appear to be expecting a string.

Comment: You're not alone: http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/1/php-is-not-easy-as-it-may-seem.html, caveat 4

Comment: @Jeemusu Well when I look at it in the watch window of my IDE, it is returning a string. As the second parameter where I am passing the PHP_URL_PATH constant is telling the parse_url method to return a specific element of the array, which is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP type hinting does not support scalar types like strings, integers, booleans, etc. It only current supports objects (by specifying the name of the class in the function prototype), interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable (since PHP 5.4).

So in your example PHP thinks you are expecting an object that is from, or inherits from, or implements an interface called "string" which is not what you're trying to do.

[PHP Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: Thanks for responding... Ok so type hinting is about enforcing type safety for method parameters, and doesn't work with simple types like string, int, bool etc... So I will just leave it out I guess....

Answer (score 1):

An unconventional answer, but you really wanted to type hint for a string, you could create a new class for it.

```
class String
{
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        if (!is_string($value)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Expected string, "%s" given', gettype($value)));
        }

        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

You can use it Javascript style

```
$message = new String('Hi, there');
echo $message; // 'Hi, there';

if ($message instanceof String) {
    echo "true";
}
```

Typehint example

```
function foo(String $str) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The reason I ended up here was I was writing a method to trim of leading and trailing '/' from a path string as I wanted to compare relative paths.  (I am new to PHP and come from a C# background).  So I did some searching and found the method ltrim, and when I right clicked on it and went to definition (I am using PHP Tools for Visual Studio as my IDE), I came to the following definition:
function ltrim(string $str, string $charlist) {/* function implementation */}
So this lead me to creating my own method that took a string in the same way.

Comment: I don't actually know what type hinting is... doesn't the following comment give the IDE what it needs to intellisense method signature:
/**
 * Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string. (Strings)
 *
 * ATparam string $str The input string.
 * ATparam string $charlist You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the charlist parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.
 *
 * return string
 */